# Any bounded orbit converges to a unique critical point if a system has no periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, periodic-functions

If a system in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no periodic orbit, and has only one critical point which is asymptotically stable, prove that any bounded orbit $(x(t):t>0)$ must converge to the unique critical point as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

I believe it is an application of the Poincare-bendixson Theorem, but I cannot seem to connect the dots. Any help?